# How can i center the logo inside vuetify app bar?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need the logo inside to be displayed exactly in the middle of the app bar. How can I achieve this result taking into consideration the other elements inside the app bar?

I tried using `v-spacer` after the `v-app-bar-icon`, but the result doesn't feel centered at all.

One example of what I am trying to achieve is the official **nuxt** site app bar (when the display is below md size): https://nuxtjs.org/

```
<v-app-bar fixed app>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon
        aria-label="show-or-hide-navigation-menu"
        @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"
      />
      <nuxt-link aria-label="home-page" to="/">
        <v-img
          v-show="searchClosed"
          :src="require('~/assets/images/example_Logo.svg')"
          max-height="55px"
          max-width="110px"
          class="mb-1"
          contain
        ></v-img>
      </nuxt-link>
      <v-spacer v-show="searchClosed"></v-spacer>
      <v-btn v-show="searchClosed" aria-label="show-user-menu" icon>
        <v-icon>mdi-account-circle</v-icon>
      </v-btn>

      <transition name="slide-fade">
        <nav-search
          v-show="!searchClosed"
          @search-opened="searchClosed = false"
          @search-closed="searchClosed = true"
        ></nav-search>
      </transition>

      <v-btn
        v-show="searchClosed"
        aria-label="show-or-hide-search-input"
        icon
        @click="searchClosed = false"
      >
        <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this-

**1. Try putting the `v-spacer` before and after the logo image-**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-app-bar
        color="deep-purple accent-4"
        dense
        dark
        >
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-img
          src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
          max-height="55px"
          max-width="110px"
          class="mb-1"
          contain
          ></v-img>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-btn icon>
          <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn icon>
          <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-app-bar>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**2. Use the grid system-**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-app-bar
        color="deep-purple accent-4"
        dense
        dark
        >
        <v-row>
          <v-col align="start">
            <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
          </v-col>
          <v-col align="center">
            <v-img
              src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
              max-height="55px"
              max-width="110px"
              class="mb-1"
              contain
              ></v-img>
          </v-col>
          <v-col align="end">
            <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-app-bar>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```